# Restart visual Studio with same project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, restart, visual-studio-extensions

Often when you install a **Visual Studio Extension** to **Visual Studio 2012** it gives you an option to restart (with  the same project open and just as you left it).

Is there a way to *MANUALLY* **restart Visual Studio** with the **same project open**, for when VS starts running like a dog and intellisense has given up?

I see there are extensions for [VS2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f27f5495-3987-4e0f-8ce3-9a95efc05ce0) and [VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/01f0a1ae-1513-48dd-9cf0-efb38419b480/view/), but could not find one for VS2012.

Comment: If you've got a problem with Intellisense, I'd look to see if its database (ncb file) is corrupt.  That would explain the "slow down".

Comment: OK, I will give that a go. It is normally ok until VS has been open for over half a day. Then it really needs a restart to get it back up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    string vs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    string solution = DTE.Solution.FullName;
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.Exit");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(vs, '"' + solution + '"');
}
```

Comment: I'll try that now. Thank you.

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you.

Comment: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) *"Avoid overt self-promotion: The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. **However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.**"*

Comment: @IInspectable I've added my affiliation with Visual Commander, though the answer is more about the code that can be used with other Visual Studio extensions.